# Laravel - Passing a variable from a function to another function

Tags: php, laravel, controller

The question is pretty simple, all I want to do is to use a variable from another function, but it doesn't get recognized.

Any help would be appreciated.

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->getAllUsers();
        return view('home')->with('users', $users);
    }

    public function getAllUsers()
    {
        $users = User::get();
    }
```

Comment: Do 2 things, In your `getAllUsers` function add this code `return $users;` and  add this code in your `index` function `$users = $this->getAllUsers();`.

Answer (score 1):

let the second function return the values you want:

```
public function index()
    {
      $users=  $this->getAllUsers();
        return view('home')->with('users', $users);
    }

    public function getAllUsers()
    {
        return User::get();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the getAllUsers method, but you're not storing it in a variable. Also the getAllUsers method should `return` all users.

```
public function index()
{
    //Store it in the $users variable.
    $users = $this->getAllUsers();
    return view('home')->with('users', $users);
}

public function getAllUsers()
{
    return User::get();
}
```